# mongoDB async driver java - unable to connect with authentication

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Recently we've updated our `mongoDB` with port `35489` and also with `authentication` and `roles` to the database.
I've granted `readWrite` and `readWriteAnyDatabase` roles for a user and can successfully connect from our `c#` coding from mentioning it from the web.config

**My web.config:**

```
<add key="MongoConnectionString" value="mongodb://readWriteUser:********@192.168.1.225:35489/admin" />
```

Now, my problem is I'm `uanble to connect` to `mongoDB` from `java async driver` and it is throwing an exception like

**Exception**

Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:35489 com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='AdminAllDatabases', source='admin', password=, mechanismProperties={}} at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61) at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32) at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99) at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44) at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:35489. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "code" : 18, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." } at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170) at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123) at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32) at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:99) at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:58) ... 6 common frames omitted

**My async java driver code:**

```
public static final String DEFAULT_URI = "mongodb://readWriteUser:******@localhost:35489/";  

public static synchronized ConnectionString getConnectionString() 
{
    if (connectionString == null) 
    { 
       connectionString = new ConnectionString(DEFAULT_URI); 
    } 
    return connectionString; 
}

public static synchronized MongoClient getMongoClient() 
{  
   if (mongoClient == null) 
   { 
      mongoClient = MongoClients.create(getConnectionString()); 
   } 
   return mongoClient; 
}
```

we've tried with both localhost and ip address, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone suggest me the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you set the auth mechanism? And the auth db? http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.3/driver-async/reference/connecting/authenticating/

Comment: No..I haven't mentioned those..
are they mandatory to mention?

Comment: Its best practise to and required if not using a default mechanism.